# was unexpected at this time. Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-emulator

I have an error that the emulator cannot be connected and it keeps showing this every time I enter a command, for example:

```
C:\dev\flutter_windows_3.10.5-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
<< was unexpected at this time.
Process finished with exit code 255
```

```
C:\Users\MSI_Q>flutter -v << was unexpected at this time.
```

Please help me fix it